# Convert string to datetime with time zone

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datetime

i have this value inside a TextBox:

```
  var date = "2015-09-03" + TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset
```

How i can  save it to the database as DateTime with this value

```
2015-09-03+07:00 // with time zone offset information ,here the value can change by zone
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't save this as a `DateTime`. A `DateTime` does not have any part to keep UTC offset.

I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead (which is little bit better) and save it's [`.DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`.Offset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.offset(v=vs.110).aspx) properties in a `datetime` and `time` typed columns in your database.

```
string s = "2015-09-03+07:00";
DateTimeOffset dto;
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-ddK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                 DateTimeStyles.None, out dto))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dto);
}
```

Both `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` are time zone *awareness*. That's why;

- [Time Zone `!=` Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: Dear Soner Gönül thanksa lot for the tips and clear explanation ,it is works well .